# How can I export an async initialized object in commonjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, commonjs

I want to be able to use an object "client" (that is returned from an async function) by importing it like:

`import {client} from './api'`
then using it like:
`console.log(await client.getPets())`

Note that I'm not calling await to resolve client itself, I'm calling await to resolve the getPets method.

I currently have a file called api/index.ts where I'm initializing the client:

```
async function get_client() {
    const api = new OpenAPIClientAxios({
        definition: 'http://localhost/api/openapi.json', axiosConfigDefaults: {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${get_bearer()}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        },
    })
    api.init();
    api.withServer({ url: "http://localhost/" });
    return await api.getClient();
}
```

Since I'm using commonjs with electron (I need to use this to be able to "import" modules) I can't use top level await like shown in the export of this file. I've tried:

```
export const client = get_client().then(client => {return client})
```

and

```
export default new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(get_client());
});
```

Both result in the import of client:

`import client from './api'` or `import {client} from './api'`

to be a `Promise<ClientType>` not `ClientType`

My goal here is to get the object returned by the line `return await api.getClient();` to not be imported as a `Promise<ClientType>` but rather just `ClientType` which has the getPets method.

Comment: Making it an await creates a promise. You'll need to await that promise to get access to the client. However, there is no guarantee you'll have a viable client since the client may have hit a catch due to an error. You could update a variable though and reference that. For example, `let cli;` then set `cli = client` within a `then` or after an await

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @Dom. Whenever I assign a variable to the output of a .then() like you suggested, it comes back undefined. If I instead return like ```.then(res => return res)``` I always get a promise back.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski The making of general API calls in electron. I have an API spec'd out in python, I don't want to write every call by hand, hence the autogeneration.  To take it one step further, I don't want to init the package every time I want to make a call, I simply want to import the client and make an API call.